# apache reverse proxy with ldap authentication

Tags: apache, ssl, reverse-proxy, centos6, mod-proxy

have put together a frankenconfig from a few articles that is giving me a few issues. What I am trying to do is create a reverse proxy for splunk that adds authentication against our ldap directory and wraps the the http splunk page in ssl.

This config is working correctly:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

This config is shows the auth method I am hoping to use however it throws a server error after auth completes:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from All
        AuthName "Authorisation"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
        AuthLDAPUrl "ldaps://10.0.0.66:636/cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=net?uid"
        Require ldap-group cn=ipausers,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=net
        Satisfy any
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Environment:

- Linux splunk.test.example.net 2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 12 00:41:43 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- httpd-2.2.15-30.el6.centos.x86_64
- mod_ssl-2.2.15-30.el6.centos.x86_64
- openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.4.x86_64

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're off-topic, but you also need to show the rest of the mod_ldap configuration, specifically how you tell it to search for users and groups.

Comment: That is the full config aside from the default for apache/centos. The <proxy> config is taken from a working .htaccessfile